# "View Ad Targeting Information" shows "Advertising information isn't available right now. Try again later"

Tags: iphone, ios, privacy

[Control how Apple delivers advertising to you on iPhone](https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/control-how-apple-delivers-advertising-to-you-iphf60a6a256/ios)

> Go to Settings  > Privacy > Apple Advertising > View Ad Targeting
> Information.
>
> The information is used by Apple to deliver more relevant ads in the
> App Store, Apple News, and Stocks. Your personal data isn’t provided
> to other parties.

[image]

[image]

I tried about 6-9 times at different timestamps and always get

`Advertising information isn't available right now. Try again later`. It seems never working. Is there and issue at my end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no Ad Targeting Information because you have "Personalized Ads" turned off. The message could be a little clearer.